# jQuery tools validator: url and %20

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using jQuery tools validator to validate url but it consider a url with %20 as invalid (you can test this with the sample reg form here: http://www.jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html )

Everything works fine if the url contains a space character instead of %20.

The problem is that when you copy a url from Chrome url box you always get %20 instead of spaces. So copy from Chrome and paste to my form won't work.

Is it correct to consider url with %20 invalid and url with space char valid?

Comment: Why don't you replace the url encoded sign with a space temporarly?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to consider url with %20 invalid and url with space char valid?

No. URLs may not include raw spaces. They must be represented as `%20` (or `+` if using form encoding)

Comment: ok so I think that the regex in jQuery tools validator should be changed from:
/^(https?:\/\/)?[\da-z\.\-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}[#&+_\?\/\w \.\-=]*$/i
to:
/^(https?:\/\/)?[\da-z\.\-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}[#&+_%\?\/\w\.\-=]*$/i